# SP - CAML Query with three AND operators

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml, spquery

I have a CAML Query with range between two dates and one text from DropDownList.

W**here I'm wrong in this query:**

```
myquery.Query = "
    <Where>
        <And>
            <FieldRef Name='Company'/><Value Type='Text'>" + ddComFilter.SelectedItem.Text + "</Value>
            <Gt>
                <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtFrom.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
            </Gt>
            <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtTo.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
            </Lt>
        </And>
    </Where>";
```

**PS--> This is working :**

```
<And>
            <Gt>
                <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtFrom.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
            </Gt>
            <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtTo.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
            </Lt>
        </And>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not have more than 2 statements in every `<And>` / `<Or>` tag. Also you seem to be missing an `<Eq>` (or whatever you need) around your first `<FieldRef>` tag.

So instead do this

```
myquery.Query = "
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Company'/><Value Type='Text'>" + ddComFilter.SelectedItem.Text + "</Value>
            </Eq>
            <And>
                <Gt>
                    <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtFrom.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
                </Gt>
                <Lt>
                    <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtTo.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
                </Lt>
            </And>
        </And>
    </Where>";
```

Comment: I know about it, he wanted to go 7 minutes.. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

An "and" can only have 2 child nodes, thus you should amend your CAML:

```
myquery.Query = "
<Where>
<And>
    <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Company'/><Value Type='Text'>" + ddComFilter.SelectedItem.Text + "</Value>
    </Eq>
</And>
    <And>
        <Gt>
            <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtFrom.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
        </Gt>
        <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name='DateOfCompletion'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtTo.SelectedDate.ToString("s") + "</Value>
        </Lt>
    </And>
</Where>";
```

Comment: You're missing the outer `<And>`